# Deleting a portion from a string in ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I just want to delete a portion from a string.

My string: `"&product=Software"`

Need output: `"Software"`

Tried `delete`, `split` , `slice` but doesn't work. Can someone help me on this? I am very very new to Ruby.

Comment: `"&product=Software".split("=").last`

Comment: I do not want array and other part. I just want Software as output string.

Comment: @User0234 The `.split.last` will do exactly that.

Comment: @User0234 Did you even try that code in irb?

Comment: Your question is unclear: what is the *precise* code that "doesn't work"? In what way doesn't it work? Do you get an error message? What is its precise text? What line does it refer to? Are you getting wrong output? What output do you get? What output do you expect and why?

Answer (score 1):

It's slightly surprising, but Ruby lets you use `[]` and assignment to "overwrite" the substring you want to replace:

```
x = "&product=Software"

x['&product='] = ''

x # "Software"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "&product=Software"

str['&product='] = '' # method 1

str.sub!('&product=', '') # method 2
```

But if you wanna be smarter about it...

```
str = '&product=Software&price=19.99'
h = {}

str.split('&').each do |s|
  next if s.length == 0
  key, val = s.split '='
  h[key] = val
end

puts h  # {"product"=>"Software", "price"=>"19.99"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another two ways of achieving this:

Using split:

```
2.3.0 :014 > "&product=software".split('=')[1]
=> "software"
```

Using sub:

```
2.3.0 :015 > "&product=software".sub(/^.*?=/,'')
 => "software"
```